# Incompatible pointer types assigning to MGLStyleValue from NSExpression

Tags: ios, mapbox, polyline

I have implement MAPBOX in my app. I have problem to customise Polyline color and width. here is the code that i have implement.

```
MGLPolyline *polylineFirst = [MGLPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:routeCoordinates count:routeFirst.coordinateCount];

MGLShapeSource *source = [[MGLShapeSource alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"polyline" shape:polyline options:nil];
MGLLineStyleLayer *lineStyle = [[MGLLineStyleLayer alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"polyline" source:source];

lineStyle.lineColor = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:[UIColor yellowColor]];
lineStyle.lineWidth = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:@5];

[self.mapView.style addSource:source];
[self.mapView.style addLayer:lineStyle];
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expressions replaced [style functions](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.8/using-style-functions-at-runtime.html) in v4.0, It looks like you are using an earlier version of the Maps SDK.

The style functions equivalent of your code would be:

```
   lineStyle.lineColor = [MGLStyleValue valueWithRawValue:[UIColor yellowColor]];
   lineStyle.lineWidth = [MGLStyleValue valueWithRawValue:@5];
```

You may find [this sample code](https://github.com/mapbox/ios-sdk-examples/blob/4e490d9eee10d4bd8673f881eb271dcc3a309b68/Examples/ObjectiveC/LineStyleLayerExample.m) helpful.